# What are the principal moments of inertia? (In relation to eigenvalues, eigenvectors and point masses)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I don't have an actual question however I would like know and understand how to calculate the principal moment of inertia of a mass. What is the principal moment of inertia? 
To find it, do I need eigenvalues and eigenvectors?
For example, if there were two unit masses located at (x, y, z) and (x, y, z). Where the eigenvalues determined are 1 and 2. And the eigenvectors are (-1, -1, 1)' and (0, 0, 1)'. (These are entirely made up to aid in my explanation).

Any thoughts and knowledge on this topic would be greatly appreciated. I apologise for how vague my question is.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. You can't just make up "eigenvalues" and "eigenvectors"; they are computed from the inertia matrix of the rigid body in question (and there's *three* of each). And what do you mean by two unit masses, both at (x,y,z)?

Comment: @HansLundmark I understand, however I don't have a question on hand. For the unit masses I was refering to points which I have called x, y, z as I said earlier, I dont have a question on hand. So when you say they are computed from the inertia matrix, does this mean they are the leading diagonal in this matrix?

Comment: No, of course not. It means that they are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix... But seriously, this is explained in every mechanics textbook. It would be much more useful if you asked a question like "I'm trying to learn this from [insert specific book or other source here], and I'm stuck at this step". It's almost impossible to give a sensible answer to a question which basically says "I have no idea even what I'm asking about".

Comment: And regarding the unit masses, what I was asking about is why you have both masses at *the same point*? That's just like having a single point mass $m=2$ at the point $(x,y,z)$, and moments of inertia of a point mass are not very meaningful...

Comment: @HansLundmark ahh.. I understand yes sorry about that confusion, the point masses were meant to be different. Well that is why I have resorted to here as I have not found any clear information nor do I have a mechanics textbook. I know my question was vague and I stated that, and am simply asking for any knowledge on the topic at all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, calculate the moment of inertia tensor $\mathbf{I}$. This is done by integrating the moment of inertia of each mass element about the origin, as follows
$$
\mathbf{I} = \int \left(r^2\mathbf{E} - \mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}\right)\rho(\mathbf{r})d^3\mathbf{r}
$$
where $\mathbf{E}$ is the identity tensor and $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ is the mass density. If you simply have a collection of point masses $m_i$ at locations $\mathbf{r}_i$, this integral reduces to a sum over those masses:
$$
\mathbf{I} = \sum_i \left(r_i^2\mathbf{E}-\mathbf{r}_i\mathbf{r}_i\right)m_i.
$$
So how does $\mathbf{I}$ relate to the principal axes? Well, the principal axes are the axes of rotation where the angular momentum $\mathbf L$ is parallel to the angular velocity $\boldsymbol\omega$. By construction, the moment of inertia tensor satisfies
$$
\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{I}\cdot\boldsymbol\omega
$$
which immediately tells us that the principal axes are simply the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{I}$, and the moment of inertia about each of those axes is the corresponding eigenvalue.

If you need to know how to find the eigenvectors of an arbitrary matrix, there should be plenty of answers around here that relate to that.

Comment: so the principal moments of inertia are simply the eigenvalues ?

Comment: @thisguy123 Yes, the principal moment of inertia for an axis is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: Thankyou! Your answer clearly explains everything. I already know how to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues.